# How to define a OneToMany relation with multiple mappedBy columns and one of them has fixed value in doctrine 2 & symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I'm building a CMS using symfony 4 framework, where you might have content modules like pages or blogs...

Each one of these modules have a set of content blocks, meaning `Page has a OneToMany relation with ContentBlock` and `Blog has a OneToMany relation with ContentBlock`.

I'm totally new to doctrine-orm. However, I already made an abstract `MappedSuperclass` class named `Content`:

```php
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class Content
{
    /**
     * @var Collection|ContentBlock[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ContentBlock", mappedBy="id") <- I need to add one more column with a defined value (entity type) which refers to entity name
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"sort"="ASC"})
     */
    protected $blocks;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->blocks = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addBlock(ContentBlock $block): self
    {
        if (!$this->blocks->contains($block)) {
            $block->setEntityId($this->getId());
            $block->setEntity(self::class);
            $this->blocks[] = $block;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBlock(ContentBlock $block): self
    {
        if (!$this->blocks->contains($block)) {
            $this->blocks->removeElement($block);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ContentBlock[]
     */
    public function getBlocks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->blocks;
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return self::class;
    }
}
```

And made the content entities inherit from it, like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
class Page extends Content
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;
```

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BlogRepository")
 */
class Blog extends Content
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;
```

And here is the `ContentBlock` entity:

```php
class ContentBlock
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $entity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $entity_id;

    // more columns in addition for their setters and getters
```

What I need to know is how to define the relation between `ContentBlock` and other entities where the `ContentBlock::$entity_id` is representing the `Content::$id`, and `ContentBlock::$entity` is `"App\Entity\Blog"` for the blogs and `"App\Entity\Page"` for the pages, in other words "should define the entity type".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm defining the wrong `MappedSuperclass` class, it should be the other way around, so the `ContentBlock` should be split into separate children classes, and each children class must define the second column with the fixed value which corresponds to the other entity of the relation. Meaning:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
abstract class ContentBlock
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    // the other fields of each ContentBlock with setters an
}
```

And this abstract entity is used as a parent for different blocks type, like `PageContent`:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageContentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="content")
 */
class PageContent extends ContentBlock
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Page", inversedBy="blocks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $entity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $entity_type = Page::class; // <- The second column has a fixed value

    public function getEntity(): ?Page
    {
        return $this->entity;
    }

    public function setEntity(?Page $entity): self
    {
        $this->entity = $entity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntityType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->entity_type;
    }

    public function setEntityType(string $entity_type): self
    {
        $this->entity_type = $entity_type;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the `Page` entity has a OneToMany relation with `PageContent` entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PageContent", mappedBy="entity", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $blocks;

    /**
     * @return Collection|PageContent[]
     */
    public function getBlocks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->blocks;
    }

    public function addBlock(PageContent $block): self
    {
        if (!$this->blocks->contains($block)) {
            $this->blocks[] = $block;
            $block->setEntity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBlock(PageContent $block): self
    {
        if ($this->blocks->contains($block)) {
            $this->blocks->removeElement($block);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($block->getEntity() === $this) {
                $block->setEntity(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

So each module will have its own entity class (`Page`, `Blog`...) and content entity class (`PageContent`, `BlogContent`...) which has an `$entity` property (foreign key) to define the relation with the module entity, and an `$entity_type` with a fixed value depending on the name of the module entity.

Or you can simply have separated table for each content entity, without the need to the `$entity_type` if that suites your needs better.